# Large standard error when variance equals zero

Tags: r, logistic, lsmeans

The function `ggemmeans()` is producing very large standard errors when the within-group variance equals zero. I'm using `ggemmeans()` to extract estimated marginal means from a binomial GLM. The GLM models the proportion of seeds recovered from each field site (n = 6) and is coded as:

```r
model <- glm(prop_seeds_recovered ~ site_id, data = recovery, 
             family = binomial, weights = num_seeds_planted)
```

The issue is that the standard errors (and CIs) are massive for sites where all seeds were recovered (i.e. `prop_seeds_recovered = 1` for all replicates):

```r
ggemmeans(model, 'site_id')

x            | Predicted |      SE |       95% CI
-------------------------------------------------
HB-Above     |      1.00 | 5622.65 | [0.00, 1.00]
HB-High      |      0.94 |    1.03 | [0.69, 0.99]
HB-High edge |      1.00 | 5622.65 | [0.00, 1.00]
HB-Low edge  |      0.94 |    1.03 | [0.69, 0.99]
NK-Above 1.5 |      1.00 | 5622.65 | [0.00, 1.00]
NK-Above 2   |      1.00 | 5622.65 | [0.00, 1.00]
NK-High edge |      1.00 | 5622.65 | [0.00, 1.00]
NK-Middle    |      0.83 |    0.63 | [0.59, 0.95]
```

It seems to me that standard errors should be small since there's no variation. Are the large SE's a result of the fact that the equation for standard error (SE = σ/sqrt(n)) has a 0 for the numerator?

Here's an example of how my data is structured:

```r
     site_id plot seeds_original seeds_recovered seeds_missed prop_recovered
1 HB-Above    1      3               3            0             1
2 HB-Above    3      3               3            0             1
3 HB-Above    7      3               3            0             1 
4 HB-Above    9      3               3            0             1
5 HB-Above   13      3               3            0             1
6 HB-Above   15      3               3            0             1
```

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately these models require variation to make estimates.

Comment: Hi @llewmills, thanks for confirming my suspicions. I'm not able to collect more data so is there anything I can do to get a more reasonable SE?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do to get a more reasonable SE. If there's no variation most inferential tests tend not to work. When I have been In similar situations I abandon the logistic GLM and used a 1-sample test for equality of proportions. Your output looks like Stata but in R the `prop.test()` function will do it. It's a relatively dumb test compared to a logistic GLM, it just tests how different the observed proportion is from a nominal probability of success (which you nominate). For example in R if you run:

```
prop.test(10,10,p=0.5)
```

...which tests how likely it is that observing 10 target events out of 10 trials is random (i.e. probability of event = 0.5), it yields the following output
    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

```
data:  10 out of 10, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 8.1, df = 1, p-value = 0.004427
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6554628 1.0000000
sample estimates:
p 
1
```

In this case the p-value is 0.004, which says it's very unlikely that the observed proportion is due to randomness. I don't know if this is the sort of thing you are trying to test or not, and you would have to correct for multiple comparisons across six sites (six tests), but I have found it helpful in the past when I get 100% events-per-trial.

You can also run 2-sample proportion tests, testing whether two sets of proportions are different.